# Addon-sdk websocket keeps disconnectiong

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to open permanent websocket connection to a server in firefox extension. So I've created page-mod in main.js

```
_stickyInterface = pageWorker.Page({
    contentURL : self.data.url('wsInterface.html')
});
```

interface looks this way:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    //const HOST = 'ws://localhost:9099';
    const HOST = 'ws://10.0.0.32:9099';
    // subprotocol-key: used when server handles communication of more applications.
    // With subprotocol is server able to delegate messages for this purpose
    //const STICKY_SUBPROTOCOL_KEY = "Myris_JsApi"; 
    const STICKY_SUBPROTOCOL_KEY = 'sticky-protocol';
    // internal identifier of this app
    const APP_KEY = "Myris_Chrome";

    var _connection = null;

    var _requestQueue = [];

    _connection = new WebSocket(HOST, STICKY_SUBPROTOCOL_KEY);

    _connection.onopen = function () {

        console.log("Sticky Interface: Connection opened.");
        var JSONObject = new Object;
        JSONObject.appKey = APP_KEY;

        _connection.send(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
        console.log('sent');
    };

    _connection.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("Error ");
        console.log(evt);
        _connection.close();
    }

    //ok
    _connection.onclose = function (evt) {
        console.log("Close ");
        _connection.close();
    }

    _connection.onmessage = function(evt) {
        console.log('MESSAGE');
    }


    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Connection is opened, messages are received. But client keeps disconnecting. There is no error message in browser console. Except for these lines (and I think the last two appeard after connection disconnected)

```
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property permissions['private-browsing'] self.js:50
1413381004615   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    Saved state file does not exist.
1413381004615   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    No prefs data found.
```

and even after then, with some timeout

```
"Error " StickyInterface.html:30
error { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, NONE: 0, CAPTURING_PHASE: 1, AT_TARGET: 2, BUBBLING_PHASE: 3, ALT_MASK: 1, CONTROL_MASK: 2, SHIFT_MASK: 4, META_MASK: 8, currentTarget: WebSocket } StickyInterface.html:31
"Close " StickyInterface.html:37
The connection to ws://10.0.0.32:9099/ was interrupted while the page was loading.     StickyInterface.html:17
GET http://localhost/extensions-dummy/blocklistURL [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 13ms]
```

Connection fails, even with no activity mage. Using freshy installed Firefox 33.

Comment: email nils@mozilla.org he helps out a ton with websockets.